# Can File Contents Be Mixed Up?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, ntfs

I have an interesting case where Defrag? and power off seems to produce interesting side effects.

I have found a read only xml file which starts with binary content:

DCMPA30€×ÕÞ±# EÔ°ƒ3¡;k”€
0…\
*d*“B  ...

After 4096 bytes the "normal" xml content continues. This file is never written to so it should just keep its contents. While looking at the contents of the file I was able to track the contents down to a WinSxS manifest file belonging to Windows Defender.

> c:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_windows-defender-management-onecore_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.1198_none_49f90c98f36c2ba0.manifest

The file is 672 bytes in size and fits into one 4KB page. The question remains how this can happen? The OS is Windows 10 and a Samsung SSD with Enterprise Power Loss features to prevent dangling writes to corrupt the SSD contents.

Can Defrag cause such an issue while the machine gets a hard power cut? I am not sure if chkdisk has reported NTFS errors because the machine was installed over in between. 
Can this indicate a SSD internal data corruption or is this more a thing of NTFS and modified list not flushed to disk in time? The only tool I am aware of which could move the clusters for already allocated file would be defrag. Is this the only possible source for this error or can Defrag noch cause such a data corruption by its design?

Comment: @James: I have an UPS. The problem is that the system is shut down the hard way after a timeout which seems to cause disk corruptions. The question is how can I later find out what was causing the corruption? Was it Defrag, or the SSD or something else?

Comment: It could be anything. Cutting power to a running system can always result in corruption because processes may be in the middle of modifying things.

Comment: I want to get away from it could be anything to get some insights what others have seen in that case. I am sure there are known patterns of corruptions out there.